# AndroidManifest.xml The markup in the document following the root element must be well formed

Tags: android, xml

I have got Eclipse to generate a Basic android Hello World app, But it has 2 errors: first, in my AndroidManifest.xml on these two lines:
 
I get The markup in the document following the root element must be well formed, Also My R.java Will not generate, no matter how many times I clean my project. Any Answers?

the manifest is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NHDU6/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfkingsley.maclogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>


<!--
     Declare the contents of this Android application.  The namespace
     attribute brings in the Android platform namespace, and the package
     supplies a unique name for the application.  When writing your
     own application, the package name must be changed from "com.example.*"
     to come from a domain that you own or have control over.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfkingsley.maclogin" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_home"
        android:label="@string/home_title" >
        <activity
            android:name="Home"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Wallpaper"
            android:icon="@drawable/bg_android_icon"
            android:label="Wallpaper" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks, Jonathan

Comment: Did you delete a project and then crate another with the same name?

Comment: No, the issue was I had more than one app tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your manifest,

You should not specify more than one `Manifest` and You should not specify  more than one `<application>`  tags.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.jfkingsley.maclogin" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="h" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Home"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Wallpaper"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="Wallpaper" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are missing something, but sometimes doing a simple re-format of code: CTRL+SHIFT+F, clears the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your manifest file. The error is caused because you have 2 declarations of `<manifest />` tag.

It begins with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfkingsley.maclogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Then some comments follow and another declaration starts:

```
<!--
     Declare the contents of this Android application.  The namespace
     attribute brings in the Android platform namespace, and the package
     supplies a unique name for the application.  When writing your
     own application, the package name must be changed from "com.example.*"
     to come from a domain that you own or have control over.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfkingsley.maclogin" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Your either forgot to comment one of the manifests tag, confused something, or following a wrong tutorial. The AndroidManifest file should have only one `<manifest />` tag

Answer (score 0):

The Auto-generated AndroidManifest.xml file has some problem by itself. There is two manifest tag and two uses-sdk tag inside it. That is the problem. Do as follows:
1- Delete the closing tag of first manifest tag which is:
`</manifest>`
2- Delete definition tag of the second manifest tag which is:

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.learn2develop.fragments"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
```

3- If there is two uses-sdk tag, also delete the second uses-sdk tag.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new activity to my app, and it gave this error after. The manifest disappeared from android-studio completely. 
I had to edit the manifest with a text editor. It seems that when I added a new activity, Android Studio created a new  tag then added the new activity tag inside in the manifest file, rather than just adding the  tag with the new activity in the manifest. 
After you update the manifest, the project worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

< xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.groofy">

```
<activity
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUp"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score -1):

/> should not be at the end of the file I had the same issue the error means the xml file is not correctly formatted you should try removing the / in front of the > or simply  reformat

Comment: There's no `/>` at the end of the file in the question. What are you talking about?